# Increase thickness of cylinder in three js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to increase thickness of cylinder using ThreeBSP. Using this http://jsfiddle.net/gerdonabbink/tephoLr1/133/  fiddle but it gives me an constructor error.

[Type Error: ThreeBSP is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to2PK.png)

currently i am using `<script type="module">` to load all JS file using 'import' keyword. so is there need to alter library? because i haven't seen any export statement in library so, or is there any other way is available to increase thickness of cylinder?

[My Code Sample 'Instead of 'THREE' i used 'Mine' as module'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jMAo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form such cylinder, using the approach with `THREE.Shape` and `THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry()`:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js'; 
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(3, 5, 8); 
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true}); 
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 

var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); 

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var arcShape = new THREE.Shape(); 
arcShape.absarc( 0, 0, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false ); 
var holePath = new THREE.Path(); 
holePath.absarc( 0, 0, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
arcShape.holes.push( holePath );

var extrudeGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(arcShape, {depth: 6, curveSegments: 36, bevelEnabled: false});
extrudeGeom.translate(0, 0, -3);
extrudeGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(extrudeGeom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(cylinder);


renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => { renderer.render(scene, camera); });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot, so actually user entering an height and radius of both upper and lower which always have different with an angle to bend this cylinder e.g if height is 10 and upper hole radius is 5 and bottom is 2 with degree 50 so cylinder  have to bend inside. but it have started to bend from point 7 to up-to 10. so can you help me in this

Comment: You can use `THREE.LatheBufferGeometry()`. I think it's better to ask a new question with detailed explanation of what you want to achieve.